# No matching function for call in this code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This is another "What's worng with my code when I get 'No matching function for call'-error". The problem is that the questions about that are to specific andcan't really be applied to code in general. My question will also be quite specific.

My code:

---

```
string largestNumber(vector<int>& nums)
{
    string finalAnswer = "";
    vector<int> answer{nums[0]};
    if (nums.size() == 1)
    {
    return toStringconverter(nums[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1 ; i < nums.size() ; i++)
        {
            answer.insert(getNumber(answer, nums[i]), nums[i]);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < answer.size() ; i++)
    {
        finalAnswer = finalAnswer + toStringconverter(answer[i]);
    }
}
```

---

I get the error in the `answer.insert(getNumber(answer, nums[i]), nums[i]);`-line. This is part of a solution for a problem on the leetcode coding site.

Sorry for net explaining better. getNumber returns an int.
int getNumber(vector& theList, int number)

Comment: What's `getNumber`? You're passing it a `vector<int>` and an `int`, my guess is that it's not how the function is declared and that's why you get the error.

Comment: First argument of [vector::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) should be an iterator.

Comment: what q&a's about this problem have in common for sure is that you are trying to call a function with a combination of parameters for which there is no overload. What overload of `insert` do you think should match the parameters you pass?

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. With the current code we cannot really say more than you already know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is `vector::insert(iterator position, const value_type& val)` to insert `val` before `position` into `answer`.

So you must tell the compiler what `getNumber` really does and how to convert its `int` return to an `iterator`. It might as simple as `answer.begin() + getNumber(answer, nums[i])` but it might be better to change `getNumber` to return an `iterator` directly.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to help. How do I change getNumbers return type? I tried changing from int to iterator but that caused an error. (Sorry that I don't havve enought reputation yet to vote up this reply.)

Comment: If you change return type to iterator, you do `return answer.begin() + original_return_value;`